# How to add span in div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add span to div code below to understand my problem

```
<div class="tags">
**<span class="tag">sd<button class="close" type="button">×</button></span>**
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter tags ..." id="form-field-tags" name="tags" style="display: none;"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter tags ...">
</div>
```

`**<span>**` decribe place for insert one or many tag between div before input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```
$('<span class="tag">sd<button class="close" type="button">×</button></span>')
.insertBefore('#form-field-tags');
```

Comment: Insert a span but outside of div

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)**:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each
>   element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('div.tags').prepend('<span class="tag">sd<button class="close" type="button">×</button></span>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr3w2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prepend()`:

```
 $('div.tags').prepend('<span class="tag">sd<button class="close" type="button">×</button></span>')
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$('input.tags').prepend('<span>what you want</span>');
```